# How to get username of request from ModelViewSet class in Django rest API?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have the following code.
It allows uploading an Image using Rest API's in Django.
How ever due to the nature of this class I am unable to get the user the way it's usually done (request.user)

## view.py

```
class PhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    queryset = Photo.objects.all()  
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer

    @receiver(post_save, sender=Photo)
    def my_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        print request.user.username #How to make this work?
```

## url.py

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'avatar', PhotoViewSet, base_name='love_stackoverflow')
```

Comment: You can't... signals can fire even in the absence of an HTTP request and have no knowledge of what triggered a save on the model. If you want to be able to do something with the `user` then you need to do this in a view method/class instead of a signal handler.

Comment: I was thinking since it is possible to check the permissions.IsAuthenticated maybe it is also possible to check the requesting user.

In that case I must use this example 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser

However I do not understand how one uploads a file using that method since unlike the ModelViewSet Class method the api page does not provide a browse option.
(I have looked over plenty of similar questions, I still have trouble finding the way, curl is often suggested however it does not seem to work well)

Comment: `permissions.isAuthenticated` is being checked inside the view class, which has access to the request. You signal handler does not (and should not). It should be possible to move your logic out of a handler into the view code itself.

Comment: Does your Photo Model have a foreign key to the user whos has uploaded it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the user to the `Photo` instance, either use the [`CurrentUserDefault`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) in the PhotoSerializer (as read-only field) or [pass the user to the serializer's `save`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save) within the view's `perform_create`